# How to remove MySQL root password

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I want to remove the password for user root in localhost. How can I do that? By mistake I have set the password of root user. That's why phpmyadmin is giving an error:

`#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: Why not configure your phpMyAdmin to use the root password instead?

Comment: The MySQL documentation contains instructions on [how to reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html) in case you have forgotten it.

Comment: Note that starting with MySQL 5.7, a random root password is set by default, and you cannot remove it without disabling the `validate_password` plugin first. See my article [Removing the MySQL root password](https://medium.com/@benmorel/remove-the-mysql-root-password-ba3fcbe29870) or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/BenMorel/3aa86d9db6c6751b6ab77b3a939938fc) directly.

Comment: For all non-root users `SET PASSWORD FOR root@\`%\`=PASSWORD('');` , the percentage sign must be enclosed by the backticks

Comment: A common reason to want to remove the root password is so that you don't have to type it all the time. Another way to achieve that is to put the password in a mysql config file. (Figuring out the filepaths for mysql config files is another question... `~/.my.cnf` might work.)

`[client]\npassword = root` (replace `\n` with a newline i.e. line break)

Answer (score 457, accepted):

You need to set the password for `root@localhost` to be blank. There are two ways:

1. The MySQL [`SET PASSWORD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html) command:

   ```
   SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD(''); -- MySQL 5.x
   SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=''; -- MySQL 8.x
   ```
2. Using the command-line [`mysqladmin`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqladmin.html) tool:

   ```
   mysqladmin -u root -pType_in_your_current_password_here password ''
   ```

Comment: how can I reset password for a perticular database?

Comment: mysqladmin -u root -pcurrent_password password '' is another way to do it.

Comment: I needed to do `mysqladmin -u root -p password ''` then enter the password.

Comment: @crizCraig probably because your password wasn't `CURRENTPASSWORD`, the password argument (unlike other arguments) doesn't have a space after it.  If you omit a password then it will prompt you for one ([doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html#option_mysqladmin_password))

Comment: Using a password on the command line is not good practice.

Comment: @Dario: I forgot my mysql temporary password, how could I login now? :| I can't even change?:((

Comment: @mOna try this way:
1- turn off mysql (shutting down the service or killing it);

2- create a file containing `SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');` called `restore`;

3- call `mysqld_safe --init-file=path/to/restore`;

Finally log in and change again the password with what you prefer.

Comment: @Dario: I couldn't start with mysqld_safe, then I tried with this command `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` but I got this error: `. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).
`

Comment: @Dario: by the way, regarding mysqld_safe, I found that there is no mysqld in `/var/run`.  also, when I typr mysql in terminal, I receive this error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)`

Comment: Answer #1 works.  #2 does not.  At least for me.

Comment: @Dario C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql.exe -u root -p -e "SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');"---->ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=''; worked for me.

Comment: The command in answer is deprecated. Use the below instead.
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost='';

Comment: According to MySQL 8.0 docs:
"Rather than using SET PASSWORD to assign passwords, ALTER USER is the preferred statement for account alterations, including assigning passwords."
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html

To remove root password:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';

Answer (score 28):

I have also been through this problem,

First i tried setting my password of root to blank using command :

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');
```

But don't be happy , PHPMYADMIN uses 127.0.0.1 not localhost , i know you would say both are same but that is not the case , use the command mentioned underneath and you are done.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@127.0.0.1=PASSWORD('');
```

Just replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 and you are done .

Comment: SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD(''); worked for me