# Reverting a grant privileges statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, privileges, mantis

So I'm hacking away at some software and I decide to run the MySQL command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then I notice that my Bug tracker uses the same local MySQL server on my development PC.

Well darn ..

Now when I try to use my bug tracker (Mantis), I get an error message.

> APPLICATION ERROR #400  Database connection failed. Error received
>   from database was #1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO).   Please use the "Back" button in your web
>   browser to return to the previous page. There you can correct whatever
>   problems were identified in this error or select another action. You
>   can also click an option from the menu bar to go directly to a new
>   section.
>
> Previous non-fatal errors occurred. Page contents follow.
>
> SYSTEM WARNING: 'mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\mantis\library\adodb\drivers\adodb-mysql.inc.php'
>   line 365

I checked inside the php file and that line is where the MySQL connection is established

```
function _connect($argHostname, $argUsername, $argPassword, $argDatabasename)
    {
        if (!empty($this->port)) $argHostname .= ":".$this->port;

        if (ADODB_PHPVER >= 0x4300)
            $this->_connectionID = mysql_connect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword,
                                                $this->forceNewConnect,$this->clientFlags);
        else if (ADODB_PHPVER >= 0x4200)
            $this->_connectionID = mysql_connect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword,
                                                $this->forceNewConnect);
        else
            $this->_connectionID = mysql_connect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword);

        if ($this->_connectionID === false) return false;
        if ($argDatabasename) return $this->SelectDB($argDatabasename);
        return true;    
    }
```

Using MySQL Workbench I can see that

SHOW GRANTS;

[image: grants]

That first row seems to be the culprit, ... I think ...

Is there a way to revert this?

Thanks :)

Comment: It also seems odd that I get an access is denied error message after granting *ALL* privileges

Comment: your error message clearly says `using password: NO`. In other words, your code is not sending one to mysql, and your `grant` clearly sets a password on the account, so you're properly getting denied access.

Comment: The bug tracker (mantis) isn't my code so its best not to change that. It seems you are saying that the GRANT ALL privileges statement also adds the requirement of a password. This would be the part I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get mantis working again by

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');
```

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032054/how-to-remove-mysql-root-password)