# Forgot login for phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to access phpMyAdmin.  But it is asking for username and password. However I don't think I ever set one up. I tried to use `username="root"`, `password=""` or `password="password"` or `password="root"`. But no luck.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try  to set the password for `root@localhost` to be blank. There are two ways:

The MySQL [SET PASSWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html) command:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');
```

Using the command-line [mysqladmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html) tool:

```
mysqladmin -u root -pCURRENTPASSWORD password ''
```

For more info :- [How to remove MySQL root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032054/how-to-remove-mysql-root-password)