# Changing MySQL password every time

Tags: mysql

Every time I turn on my laptop I need to follow steps of this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.5/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html to change root password of MySQL server 5.5 to null, so I can access my project files.

Someone said to me that lets put a password to the server but I don't want that. Someone could help me to fix this problem for good?

Comment: Why are you using root? You should create a user account with persmissions you need and be done with it.

Comment: Not sure why you are against using a password but see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032054/how-to-remove-mysql-root-password OR https://ariejan.net/2010/10/26/clear-your-mysql-password/

Comment: @apesa how can I make this user tell me

Comment: ok @PaulF I will see it

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "how can I make this user tell me-' Tell you what? You're not too clear with your question or responses. You should edit your question and add more details