# How can I remove localhost root pwd for mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I remove localhost root password because phpmyadmin shows an error?

> #1045- access denied for user 'root' @localhost (using password :no)

Comment: Is it a local server with e.g. XAMPP? Or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove MySQL root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032054/how-to-remove-mysql-root-password)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032054/how-to-remove-mysql-root-password

Comment: Yes it is a local server xampp